# ReactJS - Props is Not Passed to Component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I created a project where a component shows a list of Employees.

MyEmployee component:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function MyEmployee({
  data = [],
  page = 1,
  size = 2,
  total = 0
}) {
  const [myEmployees, setMyEmployees] = useState(data);
  const [currPage, setCurrPage] = useState(page);
  const [rows, setRows] = useState(size);
  const [totalData, setTotalData] = useState(total);

  return (
    <>
      {console.log("data: ", data)}
      {console.log("myEmployees: ", myEmployees)}
      <h2>Some Employee</h2>
      {myEmployees.map((emp) => {
        console.log("iterate emp", emp);
        return (
          <div key={emp.id}>
            <span>{emp.name}</span>
            <span>{emp.email}</span>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <button>{"<"}</button>
      <span>
        {currPage} of {Math.ceil(totalData / rows)}
      </span>
      <button>{">"}</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

then in App component I pass the props:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import MyEmployee from "./MyEmployee";
import { getSomeData } from "./SomeService";

export default function App() {
  const [employees, setEmployees] = useState({});

  function getData() {
    const emp = getSomeData();
    console.log("emp: ", emp);
    if (emp?.status) {
      setEmployees(emp.data);
    }
    console.log("employees: ", employees);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {console.log("employees: ", employees)}
      <MyEmployee
        data={employees?.someEmployeeData?.obj}
        page={employees?.someEmployeeData?.page}
        size={employees?.someEmployeeData?.size}
        total={employees?.someEmployeeData?.total}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

the props come from SomeService.js:

```
export function getSomeData() {
  return {
    status: true,
    message: null,
    data: {
      someEmployeeData: {
        page: 1,
        size: 2,
        total: 5,
        obj: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: "Deas",
            email: "deas.north@somemail.com"
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: "Joey",
            email: "joey_ma2@somemail.com"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  };
}
```

[image: result]

But i see that the props are not passed as the states in MyEmployee which initialized with the props have the deafult value. what did i miss / do wrong?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-benz-45rh5w)

Comment: @chrisbyte yes, i initialized it from props data, is it the correct approach?

Comment: The data is being passed in. In MyEmployee.js you do console.log on the data and it shoes the two records. If you log page, size, and total, they will have data as well.

Comment: @chrisbyte any idea why "myEmployees" state still empty despite initialized with "data"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in the props but not setting the state inside the component, since you want them in different variables. Try adding `useEffect` in `MyEmployee.js`

```
const [myEmployees, setMyEmployees] = useState(data);
const [currPage, setCurrPage] = useState(page);
const [rows, setRows] = useState(size);
const [totalData, setTotalData] = useState(total);

useEffect(() => {
  setMyEmployees(data);
  setCurrPage(page);
  setRows(size);
  setTotalData(total);
}, [data, page, size, total]);


return (
  etc...
```

Comment: so it's not enough to initialize it in useState?

Comment: It depends on what you are doing. As @Taiwei Tuan said, you can use the props directly as they are or if you want to store them in a state (like you are showing), you have to use `useEffect`. You don't really need those extra variables (myEmployees, currPage, etc.) unless you plan on doing something with them.

Answer (score 1):

When the component is initialized, every props that are loaded in are default value, so they are either `undefined` or the fallback value that you defined in the argument. These part specific.

```
export default function MyEmployee({
  data = [],
  page = 1,
  size = 2,
  total = 0
}
```

So when the states in `MyEmployee` is initialized, they are initialized the fallback value that you have defined (`[]`, `1`,`2`, and `3`). Since the only way to update the state is to use `setState` method, all of the state like `myEmployees` and `currPage` are not being updated.

The proper way is to not store them as state and read them directly, and get the updated values from the parent component that passes those values in as props.

Of course, the other alternative would be to use the `useEffect` to update those states with `useState` when the props are updated, but that will cause many unnecessary re-render as a caveat.

Comment: in the real project, there's pagination in the render component (MyEmployee) where it comes from different API call. so based on your explanation, it's better to remove the pagination logic and put it in parent component and pass the state as props?

Comment: For your case, yes. To give you even more details, your parent App should also pass in an additional props `onPagenationChanged` that pass in as a function for the user to change the pagenation (assuming its a button, then you will pass that prop down to `MyEmployee`, `<button onclick={()=> props.onPagenationChanged(page+1)} >next</button>` and handle `setState` in `App` level inside `onPagenationChanged`, make an API call, and finally pass the latest server response to the child again. Just one rerender for the whole thing to complete for updating the pagination.